# Mesh Networking in the Chrome/Firefox Extension Evnviorment

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, browserify, mesh-network

I'm currently making a Chrome/Firefox Extension, and the extension needs to make a BLE Mesh Network using the computer's Bluetooth capabilities. Is this possible is Pure JS, or do you have to use Browserify to get Node.JS working on a chrome extention and use the [AnyMesh Library](https://github.com/AnyMesh/anyMesh-Node). Is it not possible at all? Please help

Comment: There are tutorials on basic bluetooth access ([example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web)). Anyway, you can't run node.js **inside** extension or browser because it's a separate application just like the browser itself.

Comment: So I would have to create my own Mesh Networking library? There has to be a library for vanilla JS that allows me to create a Mesh Network. Any Ideas? I just really don't want to put in the extra effort if there's already a library, you feel me?